# How to build this Concave curves to uiview at particular position in swift ios

Tags: swift, concave

I want add this dashed Line with curve to UIView in swift iOS
How to achieve this I
Image is attached with it

I want add this dashed Line with curve to UIView in swift iOS
How to achieve this I
Image is attached with it

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What's the final goal? Because you could add the dashes, and fake the "concave", after all it's just a shadow and a round mask. You can also put an image if you prefer.

Comment: Image not needed , want to draw from bezier path but I dont know How to draw like that

Answer (score 0):

if we have the image of the "Dashed Line with curve" you can create a small view with the width of your view and height of 1-2 pixel and add an UIImageView
with the "Dashed Line with curve" image all over of him.